# SQL JOIN with OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, openquery

How do I correctly join a query with a open query?
Here is a how my query is layed out right now. The query that is part of the `OPENQUERY` works by itself.

`Select d.* from db.dbo.table d
left join (select * from OPENQUERY(otherSource,'
--working query
SELECT...
left join...
inner join..') OQ
ON d.col1 = OQ.col1`

I am catching the error `'Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to reverse it, do your SELECT from the OPENQUERY. So something like:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(remotesource,'SELECT blahblah from tableA) A
RIGHT JOIN tableB B ON B.col1 = A.col1

Answer (score 2):

This syntax worked for me:

```
select 
   a.id, b.ItemId, a.Name, b.[Description]
from 
   [A_Database]..tblA a
inner join 
   openquery([linkedServerDbName], 'select * from [B_Database]..[TableToJoin]') b
ON 
   a.id = b.ItemId
```